# Upgrade Tensorflow in Anaconda from 1.2.1 to 1.3

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I want to upgrade my tensorflow package in anaconda to at least 1.3, however, i receive following message after trying to run "conda update tensorflow":

```
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

Is there a way to use v1.3 on anaconda?

Comment: For anaconda, if you use the `conda install` command you only get the TF version published on the Anaconda channels. These are usually behind the actual current TF versions. Use `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow=1.3` (or tensorflow-gpu if you wat the CUDA-enabled version)

Comment: Above comment was helpful but may have a small typo, needed equality operator instead of assignment operator in the last expression

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the version of Anaconda you have installed.

I am running Tensorflow 1.4 with Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit) (Python 3.6.1).

Comment: Mentioning `newest Anaconda` is dependent on the current date. Actual version would be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

For me `pip install tensorflow==1.3 --upgrade` was working.